# How to change crs of geometry in geopandas dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, gis, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile which I am converting into a geopandas dataframe. The crs of this shapefile is epsg:4326 and I want to convert this to epsg:3857.

```
import geopandas as gp

file_path = 'zip_poly.shp'
sf = gp.read_file(file_path)
sf = sf[['ZIP_CODE','PO_NAME','STATE','geometry']]
sf = sf.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

You can find the shapefile [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b08FSTkLRf3Ebi1qgRyAjTV8aT1pk75E).

The shapefile has around 33K zipcodes and it's taking too long to convert. Is there a better way to convert quickly?

Comment: I think the code you show is the best option you have for now (how long is too long?). It might improve with the latest version of pyproj (>2.1), and there is work underway in GeoPandas to improve the performance, but that is not yet released.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322420/how-to-change-crs-of-geometry-in-geopandas-dataframe-efficiently